# object [object Object] is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and i am  trying to call the create function listed below and keep on getting the same error which is object [object Object] is not a function  in javascript  Can anyone please help.

```
  // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.
function init() {

    //Marker
    canvasMarker = document.createElement('canvas');
    context = canvasMarker.getContext('2d');

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    document.body.appendChild(canvasMarker);

    /* This is where ths problem is encountered. */
    detector = create(canvasMarker);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(80, 20, 10);

    //Creates scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101030);
    //scene.add(ambient);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1);
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // loads texture

    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
        console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };

    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
    loader.load(texturePath, function (image) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        texture.transparent = true;
    });

    // loads model
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.load(objectPath, function (object) {

        object.traverse(function (child) {

            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                child.material.map = texture;
                child.material.transparent = true;

            }

        });

        object.position.y = -100;
        scene.add(object);

    });

    //setup three.js renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true
    });

    //canvas        
    var mycanvas = renderer.domElement;
    mycanvas.setAttribute('id', 'Canvas3d');
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(mycanvas);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

    //window listener for resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    video = document.getElementById('myvideo');

}

function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 2;
    mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 2;
}

//Animate the model
function animate() {
    // The ardetector requires that we set a flag when the canvas has changed.
    canvasMarker.changed = true;

    // Ask the detector to make a detection pass.
    detector.detect(onMarkerCreated, onMarkerUpdated, onMarkerDestroyed);

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

//Render the Model
function render() {
    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

*
var create = function (sourceCanvas) { *
    var JSARRaster = new NyARRgbRaster_Canvas2D(sourceCanvas);
    var JSARParameters = new FLARParam(sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
    var JSARDetector = new FLARMultiIdMarkerDetector(JSARParameters, 120);
    JSARDetector.setContinueMode(true);

    var getMarkerNumber = function (idx) {
        var data = JSARDetector.getIdMarkerData(idx);
        if (data.packetLength > 4) {
            return -1;
        }

        var result = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.packetLength; i++) {
            result = (result << 8) | data.getPacketData(i);
        }

        return result;
    }

    var getTransformMatrix = function (idx) {
        var mat = new NyARTransMatResult();
        JSARDetector.getTransformMatrix(idx, mat);

        var cm = new Float32Array(16);
        cm[0] = mat.m00;
        cm[1] = -mat.m10;
        cm[2] = mat.m20;
        cm[3] = 0;
        cm[4] = mat.m01;
        cm[5] = -mat.m11;
        cm[6] = mat.m21;
        cm[7] = 0;
        cm[8] = -mat.m02;
        cm[9] = mat.m12;
        cm[10] = -mat.m22;
        cm[11] = 0;
        cm[12] = mat.m03;
        cm[13] = -mat.m13;
        cm[14] = mat.m23;
        cm[15] = 1;

        return cm;
    }

    var getCameraMatrix = function (zNear, zFar) {
        var result = new Float32Array(16);
        JSARParameters.copyCameraMatrix(result, zNear, zFar);
        return result;
    }

    var persistTime = 1;
    var newMarker = function (id, matrix) {
        return {
            id: id,
            matrix: matrix,
            age: persistTime,
        }
    }

    var markers = {};
    var detect = function (onCreate, onUpdate, onDestroy) {
        var markerCount = JSARDetector.detectMarkerLite(JSARRaster, 70);
        for (var index = 0; index < markerCount; index++) {
            var id = getMarkerNumber(index);
            var marker = markers[id];
            if (marker === undefined) {
                marker = newMarker(id, getTransformMatrix(index));
                markers[id] = marker;
                onCreate(marker);
            } else {
                marker.matrix = getTransformMatrix(index);
                marker.age = persistTime;
                onUpdate(marker);
            }
        }

        for (var id in markers) {
            var marker = markers[id];
            if (marker) {
                if (marker.age-- == 0) {
                    onDestroy(marker);
                    delete markers[id];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        detect: detect,
        getCameraMatrix: getCameraMatrix,
    }
}

return {
    create: create,
}
```

This is my code. Please help.

Comment: You are creating the "create()" function as a variable in Render(). It won't be accessible to functions outside it like init(). Move the create function outside Render() where init() can see it.

Comment: It definitely looks like a scoping issue - consider trimming out some of the less relevant code for future questions. I wrote a blog post awhile back that discusses how scoping works in JavaScript - http://jordanforeman.com/understanding-javascript/

Comment: @MazeHatter the create is not in the reder

Comment: Your formatting made that very hard to see. I edited it. In the future, try to include only what's necessary to ask your question and format it in a standard way.

Comment: Also, it seems that this was probably all wrapped in some other function (based on the final `return`), but you don't show that. It's all way more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: Perhaps you should do {"create": create}. I've noticed when you have variables the same name as the member you're trying to create, without quotes things get messed up.

Comment: @MazeHatter: I'd be *very* surprised if that was an issue. Key names in an object literal are never evaluated as JS expressions. Do you have a concrete (isolated) example?

Comment: Hmmm. Thought it was an issue for me once, but can't reproduce it. Maybe I'm just thinking of JSON, since this pukes: var myobj = JSON.parse("{field: 1}");

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling init()?

It must be outside this program?

By then var create has gone out of scope.

Change var create = function () { to function create() { and you may have better luck.

**EDIT:**

If this if your (psuedo)-JS file:

```
init();
function init() { }
function create() { }

return {create: create};
```

Then you will get the error illegal return statement, because a JS file doesn't "return" a value anywhere.

That return statement at the very bottom isn't going to do anything (except throw that error);

Comment: In that case the var create = function () hasn't run yet, so its not defined. Move it above the init(), or use function create() to ensure it exists before the script runs

Comment: init is called exeactly before the function init, when i have changed the function to function create() an error occur telling me illegla return statment. Do you now how to arrage the return sttsament as well please –

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why that final return statement, if not in a function, is not useful and causes the error.