# return statement in JavaScript illegal

Tags: javascript

I am making this function in java script and keep geting the synatx error don know why please help since i am new to java script. I don knw wat is wrong. Below is the code.

```
       function create(sourceCanvas) {
    var JSARRaster = new NyARRgbRaster_Canvas2D(sourceCanvas);
    var JSARParameters = new FLARParam(sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
    var JSARDetector = new FLARMultiIdMarkerDetector(JSARParameters, 120);
    JSARDetector.setContinueMode(true);

return {
    "create": create(),
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace from the function.

Comment: Syntax problems? Check here first: http://jshint.com

Comment: `create()` return anything.  Perhaps you meant `return { create: create }`?

Comment: return {
    "create": create()***,***
}

should be:
return {
    "create": create();
}

Comment: Looks like a infinite recursion waiting to happen...

Comment: should be return { "create": create } <-- without () (which executes a function call), and without trailing comma. Or if you want to execute it, then function create { ... } needs to return something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is unintelligible.  I don't think it's a syntax problem, so much as a complete lack of understanding of how functions work. You are using objects and a function, and it seems like you don't really understand either.  I'm not saying this to be rude, just stating my perception of your question. In fact, I'll try to break it down for you.

```
function create(sourceCanvas) {
```

This is the function definition. It means that when you use the keyword "create" the computer should link to the block of code in between the curly braces {}.  You have an opening curly brace, but no closing one, so that is a syntax error. In the create function definition you have listed "sourceCanvas" as an argument. That means that you are telling the computer that you need that variable to execute the code in the body of the function.

```
   var JSARRaster = new NyARRgbRaster_Canvas2D(sourceCanvas);
    var JSARParameters = new FLARParam(sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
    var JSARDetector = new FLARMultiIdMarkerDetector(JSARParameters, 120);
    JSARDetector.setContinueMode(true);

return {
    "create": create(),
}
```

Here you are calling the "create" function. But you don't have any arguments listed. Remember how you need a "sourceCanvas" argument? That will cause another syntax error.  Also you are calling the "create" function inside the "create" function. That will cause an infinite loop that will crash your machine.

{ "create": create(), } is an object.  It has an attribute "create" and the value of "create" is whatever the function create() returns. Since there is only one attribute, you don't need the comma. That's another syntax error.

I don't know what your function is supposed to do, but here is a version that will compile:

```
function create(sourceCanvas) {
   var JSARRaster = new NyARRgbRaster_Canvas2D(sourceCanvas);
   var JSARParameters = new FLARParam(sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
   var JSARDetector = new FLARMultiIdMarkerDetector(JSARParameters, 120);
   JSARDetector.setContinueMode(true);

   return {
      JSARRaster: JSARRaster,
      JSARParameters: JSARParameters,
      JSARDetector: JSARDetector
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code here:

[object [object Object] is not a function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242474/object-object-object-is-not-a-function-in-javascript/21242839?noredirect=1#comment32000701_21242839)

Your code is laid out like this:

```
function create() {

    return {
        detect: detect,
        getCameraMatrix: getCameraMatrix,
    }
}

return { create: create };
```

So that bottom "return" is outside the create function.

Return has to be in a function.